# how to embed audio in frame 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My audio works, but is stored in frame 1. I would like it to move the audio to frame 2. It's because I use frame 1 for a small preloader and use frame 2 for all the content.

In the Library the mp3 has checkmark in "Export for ActionScript", and has "Class" set to "Song". There is no checkmark in "Export in frame 1", yet despite this, it seems that the mp3 is exported to frame 1. I have generated a size report and seen that the mp3 data ends up in frame 1. If I remove the mp3 from the project again, then I can see that the size of frame 1 drops from about 1.7 Mb down to 20 Kb.

This is the file code for the pause/play button

```
// filename: PausePlay.as
var song:Song = null;
this.song = new Song();
this.song.play();
```

This is the code that loads the song

```
// filename: Song.as 
package {
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    public class Song extends Sound {
        public function Song()
        {
            trace("Song called");
        }
    }
}
```

When searching for alternative ways to load audio, I have seen something like `[Embed source="song.mp3"]`, but when I use it I get an alert that says this syntax requires FLEX.

How can I play audio in flash AS3 with audio is embedded in frame 2 ?

Comment: Why do you want it to be embedded in frame 2? Preloading?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a preloader in frame 1 and it fills up about 20 Kb in frame 1. Frame 2 is about 7 Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

I removed the "export to actionscript" checkmark from the mp3.

I created a MovieClip containing the mp3 and assigned it the instance name "song".

I changed the toggle button code to this:

```
if (this.is_playing) {
    this.song.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0, 0);
    this.is_playing = false;
} else {
    this.song.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1, 0);
    this.is_playing = true;
}
```

Now the audio is stored in frame#2.